# If a player gets Lycanthropy, does it start immediately? Or does it take a while?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-templates, lycanthropy, disease

If my players were fighting a werewolf and one of them got bit and failed the con save, would they instantly be able to transform? Or would they have to wait a while?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for this rules text (from the section on [Lycanthropes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-l#Lycanthropes) from p. 206 of the *Monster Manual*):

> Some individuals see little point in fighting the curse and accept what they are. **With time and experience**, they learn to master their shapechanging ability and can assume beast form or hybrid form at will. Most lycanthropes that embrace their bestial natures succumb to bloodlust, becoming evil, opportunistic creatures that prey on the weak.

If a character failed the con save, they would need "time and experience" to be able to transform.

Note, also (*Monster Manual*, p. 207):

> If the character embraces the curse, his or her alignment becomes the one defined for the lycanthrope. The DM is free to decide that a change in alignment places the character under DM control until the curse of lycanthropy is removed.

The DM can decide that any character that embraces the curse becomes an NPC.  The DM probably *should* decide this, because lycanthropy is very powerful and can be unbalancing to the campaign if a player character is allowed to exist as a lycanthrope.

Comment: The other side of the question (which I don't see an answer for in the full MM text) is what happens if you're bit by a werewolf when the moon is already full, and fail your Con save.  Do you pop into beast or hybrid form on your next turn? *However, when the full moon rises, the curse becomes too strong to resist, transforming the individual into its beast form-or into a horrible hybrid form that combines animal and humanoid traits* applies if you resist the curse.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Obviously not covered in the rules, but I'd expect it to take until the *next* full moon. Lycanthropes would be *way* too dangerous (and wildly out of keeping with real world werewolf stories) if they could essentially recruit an exponentially growing army of murderous lycanthropes just by biting peasants, who immediately transform and bite more peasants, ad infinitum, until the whole town/city is nothing but werewolves. With just one werewolf initially, and each werewolf biting just two new people, just 10 iterations of that leads to 2047 werewolves.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Right, that makes sense, and is more compatible with the rules wording of *when the **next** full moon rises*.  So I think that's the answer.

Answer (score 5):

### The Rules

The *Monster Manual* entry for [lycanthropes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-l#Lycanthropes) (p. 206) says this:

> ...when the full moon rises, the curse becomes too strong to resist, transforming the individual into its beast form -- or into a horrible hybrid form that combines animal and humanoid traits. When the moon wanes, the beast within can be controlled once again.

So in terms of *unintentional* changes, if we get super technical about this, it says the change happens when the moon *rises*, so if you're bitten well after moonrise, you don't transform for that particular moon.

However, you asked if the character would "*be able to* transform", which suggests *controlling* the curse.  The MM says:

> Some individuals see little point in fighting the curse and accept what they are. With time and experience, they learn to master their shapechanging ability and can assume beast form or hybrid form at will.

Accepting and controlling the curse isn't something you can do immediately -- it requires "time and experience", so it's up to the DM but is clearly not same-night stuff.

### Your DM

As far as unintentional changes, I think "when the full moon rises" should not be read literally; it's more a poetic description than rules. I don't think it's really meant to say anything about when the curse takes hold except "during a full moon", and beyond that it's really the DM's choice.

That said, since being bitten by a lycanthrope is vastly more likely to happen during the full moon, it seems like if the transformation happened immediately under those circumstances, that would be a very common occurrence and you'd almost never have somebody who's infected but doesn't know it yet.

### "Traditional" lycanthropy

Most stories that involve lycanthropy as a transmissible curse or disease derive from the 1935 film *Werewolf of London*, which is a surprisingly recent source for a monster with such a long history in folklore. The much more famous *The Wolf Man* from 1941 (starring Lon Chaney Jr.) used slightly different rules, but was in many respects the same, particularly with how the curse first takes effect.

In these films and many of their descendants, a werewolf infection doesn't take hold until the *next* full moon after the injury, nearly a month later. Your players are most likely going to expect that to be how things work, whether the rules state it clearly or not.

For the record, most or all werewolf stories prior to the aforementioned Universal films treat lycanthropy as something the werewolf acquires through a gift or curse by a higher (or lower) power, but it affects only the person in question and can't be passed to another (except in a few cases where the transformation is related to a specific object or piece of clothing, and the item can be passed along -- but that's not a curse at all, it's just a magic item).

Comment: Thank you for the interesting historical context. It is answers like this that make it a pleasure to peruse this site.

Comment: The first paragraph you quoted appears to apply only to those who try to resist the curse, and thus *don't* ever master the transformation.  You left out the start of that paragraph: *A lycanthrope can either resist its curse or embrace it. By resisting the curse, a lycanthrope retains its normal alignment and personality while in humanoid form. **It lives its life as it always has, burying deep the bestial urges raging inside it. However, when the full moon rises** [your quote]*.

Comment: Another valid reading (and IMO one that's closer to how the text presents it) is that only those who resist the curse are at its mercy during the full moon, while those who master it can change *or not* at any time, including during the full moon.  That's what "at will" means, and it's not clear that the moon-forced transformation for those who haven't mastered their changing would override that.  (But as a downside, their alignment changes to chaotic evil from the werewolf statblock).

Comment: IDK if we should read anything into the existence and name of the spell Moonbeam, but I think no because it forces any shapechanger to revert to their *original* form, so a lycanthrope would be forced to humanoid, not beast form.  So it's just a themed spell.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm honestly not sure what part of my answer you're disagreeing with. It sounds like you're reading in something I didn't say. I'm not claiming the first two quotes fit together in any way; in fact it's the opposite, I'm saying the basic rules are thus-and-such, but if you mean to talk about *controlling* the curse, then the rules say something different.